Origin of the Term "Entire Function" (ganze Funktion, fonction entière, etc.)
I'm trying to track down the first use of the term "entire function", but so far, all that I've been able to establish is that it was at least known to Gauss in 1799, because he uses it in his Demonstratio nova theorematis. Does anyone know who was the first to use it, and what properties they circled in on?
Thanks in advance

Below two sources point at d'Alembert's paper on his FTA proof attempt (1746) containing perhaps the answer you seek: Baltus, C. (2004). D'Alembert's proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Historia Mathematica, 31(4), 414-428. and Bottazzini, U. (1986). The Higher calculus: A History of Real and Complex Analysis From Euler to Weierstrass, Springer. p. 126.

Could you add a full reference to Gauss? I am wondering whether he actually referred to "ganze Funktion" in the modern sense, or whether he might have referred to what is called a "ganzrationale Funktion" in modern German usage, which to my understanding is basically a polynomial.

The older English term is "integral function".
The origin of this usage becomes clear when you compare with the term "meromorphic function" (ratio of two entire functions). This comes from the Greek for "fraction". Old German term is "gebrochene Funktion" (fractional function).
By analogy with integers and fractions, entire functions form a ring, and meromorphic functions is the quotient field of this ring.
By the way, in old literature what we call "polynomials" nowadays were called "entire algebraic functions", or simply "entire functions", like in the papers on the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra that you cite.

In case anyone is interested, about 4 years ago I posted in this group a list of many older English terms now no longer used (or very little used) that, over the years, I've found helpful to know in my reading of 1800s math literature in English.

@Dave L Renfro: My favorite 19 century English term is "derogatory matrix" meaning "non-diagonalizable" :-)

Very good answer, and sort of what I figured myself, but I'm afraid I'm a bit anal here. :P I kind of need to know if they originally defined it in terms of "all powers of $x$ are 0 or positive" or, "for no value of $x$ does the function assume the value $\pm \infty$"

@StormyTeacup: Unfortunately I do not know who used the term for the first time. The word "meromorphic" comes from the book of Briot and Bouquet of 1845. But the words "entire", "integral" and "ganze" are much older, their use goes back to 18 century.

@AlexandreEremenko Annoying! Thanks all the same! :) (What's annoying is that I have yet to find a single mathematics textbook from the 19th century where they anywhere even DEFINE explicitly what an entire function is. They all just assume that the reader already knows it. These days of course, you'll have no problems finding a textbook that explicitly defines what a polynomial is.)

@StormyTeacup: yes. I have not searched specially, but I expected this result:-)
